# PDO fetch returns no results

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to fetch results from a database, it returns no errors and it returns no results. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

```
try {
    $db_connection = new PDO("mysql:host = $hostname; dbname = $database", $username, $password);
    //$db_connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT );  
    $query = $db_connection->prepare("SELECT `id`, `code` FROM `mycodedatabase` WHERE 1");
    $query->execute();
    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['id'];
        echo $row['code'];
    }
    $db_connection = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: try setting `ERRMODE` to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`

Comment: Does that query return results when you run it directly in the database? What does `var_dump($query->errorInfo())` return?

Comment: @Erik ok the error gives me `Warning: PDO::setAttribute() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in`

Comment: @Mr. 1.0 ...you have to do `$db_connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );`

Comment: it says `SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected`

Comment: @Mr.1.0 - there you go. You need to select a database

Comment: put a var_dump($database) before your connexion please

Comment: i am selecting the right database i generate it from phpmyadmin http://img404.imageshack.us/img404/6797/3dcb705c8e064e76ac5945d.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to avoid using the same variable for different purposes. Use $query and $result. Don't make your code complex. I think it will help while debugging and avoid errors when logic seems correct.

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$database', "user", "pass");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$query = "SELECT id,code FROM mycodebase";
$result = $pdo->prepare($query);
$result->execute();

while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['code'];
}
```

Don't forget to change "user" and "pass"

Answer (score 1):

You must set the error mode to PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION instead of PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT (which is the default, hence why no exception is raised).